# Parsing Date and time from "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS" -------> "hh:mm aa" in android

Tags: java, android, date, date-formatting, date-parsing

> Need to convert the time to a specified format but getting a wrong result.Please help

```
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"); 
DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "hh:mm aa");   //Expecting like 05:00 

String from = "2018-02-05 17:00:52.503";
String t0   = "2018-02-05 17:00:55.372";

Date date = null;  //IST
Date date2=null;
try {
    date = readFormat.parse(from);
    date2 =readFormat.parse(to);
} catch (ParseException e) {       
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (date != null) {                       
    from = writeFormat.format(date);    //Expecting a result of 05.00 pm         
    to   = writeFormat.format(date2);   //Expecting a result of 05:00 pm

}
```

- List item## Need out put like this ##

  /*But getting an output as:

  ```
                      from= "05:08 pm"    instead of 05:00 pm
                      to  = "05:06 pm"    instead of 05:00 pm
  ```

  */

Comment: try `simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

Comment: Just read your own title. :-) You need to watch the case of those format pattern letters closely. It’s so easy to use lowercase where uppercase should have been used or vice versa. You need uppercase `HH` and uppercase `SSS`.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

        Date d = null;
        Date d1 = null;
        try 
        {
            d = input.parse("2018-02-05 17:08:52.503");
            d1 = input.parse("2018-02-05 17:06:55.372");

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String formatted = output.format(d);
        String formatted1 = output.format(d1);

        Log.i("DATE", "" + formatted);
        Log.i("DATE1", "" + formatted1);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I/DATE: 05:08 PM
I/DATE1: 05:06 PM
```

**EDIT**

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

        Date d = null;
        Date d1 = null;
        try 
        {
            d = input.parse("2018-02-05 17:00:52.503");
            d1 = input.parse("2018-02-05 17:00:55.372");

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String formatted = output.format(d);
        String formatted1 = output.format(d1);

        Log.i("DATE", "" + formatted);
        Log.i("DATE1", "" + formatted1);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I/DATE: 05:00 PM
I/DATE1: 05:00 PM
```

Comment: you can parse your date **2018-02-05 17:00:52.503** instead of my date **2018-02-05 17:08:52.503**

Comment: @NithinN.j please check my Edit answer.

Comment: @Nithin N.j  Thank you,  Happy to help you

Comment: It works.I just declared   DateFormat readFormat , DateFormat writeFormat  instead of SimpleDateFormat readFormat and SimpleDateFormat writeFormat  . Thanks for the help bro...

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.**SSS**");

Comment: This is an improvement over the format pattern string in the question, but still will not parse `2018-02-07 12:42:43.296` correctly. Also code-only answers are seldom helpful, better to explain how you are solving the problem, for us all to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `readFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered already. I just wanted to demonstrate that `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is doing a somewhat better effort to be helpful with the very common incorrect case of format pattern letters for parsing. Let’s try to use your format pattern string with the modern `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter readFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss");
```

This line throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: s`. So it doesn’t accept three lowercase `s`? It’s not telling us the case is incorrect, after all it cannot read our mind; but it does point to where one of the bugs is. Let’s correct:

```
    DateTimeFormatter readFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    String from = "2018-02-05 17:00:52.503";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(from, readFormatter);
```

This time we get a couple of lines further down, then hit a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-02-05 17:00:52.503' could not be parsed: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 17`. Clock hour of AM/PM? We didn’t intend that, again it is very precise about where the bug is. Correct this one too:

```
    DateTimeFormatter readFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

This time the string gets parsed into `2018-02-05T17:00:52.503` as desired.

On newer Android you can use `java.time` directly. For older Android add ThreeTenABP to your project and make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.